# Why isn't chrome tabs working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs, irc

For reference, here's my [project](https://github.com/sochoa/chatty).

Here's my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Chatty",
  "description": "Yet another IRC client written as a Chrome application",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my SUPER basic web page that I would like to open in a new tab:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    Hello, Chatty IRC client!
  </body>
</html>
```

And, here's how I've been trying to open the new tab:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function(){ 
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.extensions.getUrl("irc.html") });
});
```

Finally, here's my issue:  it doesn't want to open in a new tab.  Can someone help me get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing the [extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) with the [Chrome app APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index). There is some overlap in APIs, but there are also APIs that are only available to *one* of them.

Your current manifest declares a [Chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps). If you really want to have a Chrome app, then you cannot create tabs in the browser. To launch the UI, you'll have to use the [`chrome.app.window`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window) API to create a window ([`create`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create)).

If you prefer to integrate in the browser, then you have to create [an extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview). The manifest file is similar to the app, but you have to remove `"app"` (as shown below). Extensions don't have an icon in the launcher, nor access to the `chrome.app.runtime` API, so you have to choose a different way of launching your UI, e.g. via a [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction).

```
{
  "name": "Chatty",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

Since you're developing an IRC client, you probably want to create a Chrome App instead of an extension. [`chrome.sockets`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets) can be used to communicate using IRC over TCP (this low-level network API is not available to extensions).

Comment: Thanks Rob.  Is there going to be a possibility in the future where an app can open as a tab instead of a brand-new window?

Comment: @bitcycle Don't count on it.

Comment: Sad.  I dig my browser.

Comment: You can use window.open, but that only works when Chrome is the default browser.